# Driver options for Docker cloudstor azure plugin?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, azure-storage, docker-volume, persistent-volumes

I'm quite new to docker plugins feature. I managed to build container for my django app with compose file.

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    container_name: app
    entrypoint: ./entrypoint.sh
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - mediafiles:/home/app/mypersonalsite/media/blog-pics 
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass
      - POSTGRES_DB=user

volumes:
  mediafiles:
    driver: cloudstor:azure
    driver_opts:
      share_name: media
      storage_account_name: azurestoragename
```

I want to build container with external storage volume that wouldn't be hosted on azure but only connected to azure storage. I tried to connect with cloudstor azure plugin but can't get this to work althrought plugin is successfully installed and enabled on ubuntu 21.10 with this command:

```
docker plugin install --alias cloudstor:azure --grant-all-permissions docker4x/cloudstor:azure-v17.03.0-ce CLOUD_PLATFORM=AZURE AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY="***" AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT="***"
```

After trying to build compose file with azure volume options I'm getting error:

```
ERROR: create blog_mediafiles: VolumeDriver.Create: error validating metadata: not a recognized volume driver option: "share_name"
```

Can someone help or recommend any other plugin that is currently supported for azure or other network storage? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

would suugest you to use a different storage endpoint, such as `core.cloudapi.de`, you can specify it when you install the plugin:

```
docker plugin install --alias cloudstor:${STORAGE_ACCOUNT} --grant-all-permissions docker4x/cloudstor:18.06.1-ce-azure2 CLOUD_PLATFORM=AZURE AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY="${STORAGE_KEY}" AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT="${STORAGE_ACCOUNT}" AZURE_STORAGE_ENDPOINT="core.windows.net" DEBUG=1
```

**By default, the Public Azure Storage endpoint is used.**

***Reference*** [***Docker for Azure persistent data volumes***](https://gist.github.com/gregjhogan/9054ca1626486fad826b12a0d02a9830)

Please refer this [***Thread***](https://serverfault.com/questions/981770/mounting-an-azure-file-share-using-cloudstor-on-a-local-docker-container) which also help you to troubleshoot your problem.